# Chef cookbook for firefox how to set auto updates to 'never check for updates'

Tags: selenium, firefox, chef-infra, cookbook, recipe

I am after something like 
firefox['update'] = "never" equivalent in cookbook recipe for firefox as auto updates is causing issues with selenium tests. Could someone please help?

Comment: Did you google this? What have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in google. I tried the above firefox['update']='never', but didnt seem to effect anything, also no errors. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.You should really show that you spent more efforts prior to posting here...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [attributes provided by the cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/firefox/blob/master/attributes/default.rb#21) reveals the following:

```
default['firefox']['version'] = 'latest'
```

So setting this to some specific version would be a starting point (not sure if you have set this, as you seem to lack the knowledge how to find the attributes provided by a cookbook.

Regarding actually disabling updates, a quick search revealed [this thread](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1003777), which lists the option that needs to be added to the `user.js` file in your profile:

```
user_pref("app.update.enabled", false);
```